# How do I work out the correct PWM frequency for my application (motor)?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, motor, switches, pwm

I am working on a project and want to drive a motor with a 12V PWM signal (Motor connected to 12V and the Motor- net on the diagram).

I have it working, however i'm not sure how to work out the optimum frequency for my PWM to operate at for the motor i'm using. It's a brushed DC motor. I have attached the only information I have on the motor in case that helps.

Any advice or input is welcome. Thanks in advance.

**Circuit Diagram**

[image: Circuit]

**Motor Spec**

[image: Motor]

Comment: You can't drive a brushless motor that way. If it spins, it is brushed.

Comment: Thanks, for the correction. I wrote the wrong thing.

Comment: Question has been edited to correct.

Comment: Read this old case: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/242293/is-there-an-ideal-pwm-frequency-for-dc-brush-motors

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of: [Is there an ideal PWM frequency for DC brush motors?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/242293/is-there-an-ideal-pwm-frequency-for-dc-brush-motors)

Comment: you want it high enough to avoid audible kick noise and low enough to prevent capacitance turning power into heat.